# integrate scanner with c# application

Tags: c#

I am using windows 7 ultimate.
I want to integrate scanner with my c# application.
I am totally new to this.
I have searched on the internet and found something about WIA but it is not applicable in windows 7.
please help me with detailed answer.
thank you.

Comment: Why would WIA (2.0) not work in Windows 7? Afaik, it's still supported in Windows 8.

Comment: may be you need to search about your scanner API

Comment: thank you everyone for answering. but I am having issues with my scanner. I have got HP Scanjet 5300c which is no lenger supported in windows 7.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to make your HP Scanjet 5300c work on Windows 7, you may contact HP support and see if they provide such driver.

If you are looking at developing a C# app to interact with scanners, you can check out [TWAIN interface](http://twain.org/). [Here](http://www.dynamsoft.com/blog/document-imaging-how-to/using-twain-in-net-applications/) is an article that might help. (I work for the company.)

Answer (score 0):

Use the TWAIN API. NuGet package here: http://nuget.org/packages/NTwain/